# Layout constraint between Views not preserved when included as Fragment

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-fragments

I have a fragment_cameracontroller.xml which defines how buttons are laid out:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
              tools:context="cc.closeup.android.activities.TileActivity$CameraController"
              android:id="@+id/cameracontroller_layout"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:gravity="right|top">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="150dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:id="@+id/cameracontroller_layout_top"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/cameracontroller_layout_right">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/button_togglecamera"
            android:background="@android:drawable/ic_menu_camera"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/cameracontroller_layout_right"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="72dp"
            android:layout_height="72dp"
            android:id="@+id/button_talk"
            android:background="@drawable/button_talk"
            android:text="@string/talk"
            android:textColor="@color/white"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Specifically, pay attention to the `android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/cameracontroller_layout_right"` constraint, which specifies how the buttons relate to each other.

In the Preview in Android Studio, the relationship (green arrow) is honored:

[image: View Relationship]

but when I later embed that fragment xml in an Activity, both buttons are on top of each other (on the device). Here's the Activity XML:

```
<RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    <fragment
        android:name="cc.closeup.android.activities.TileActivity$CameraControllerFragment"
        android:id="@+id/cameracontroller"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_cameracontroller"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I inflate the fragment with the following static code snippet:

```
public static class CameraControllerFragment extends Fragment {
    @Override public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_cameracontroller, container, false);
    }
}
```

Is there anything that I do wrong? I know I may lose width and height of the fragment's root layout in such a case, dependent on how I inflate, but that relationship is between two child views.

Comment: I fixed the problem by removing gravity from the outer XML and placing all childs directly into the parent. Also, I defined constraints between each child and the parent, such as: `android:layout_marginTop="15dp" android:layout_marginRight="5dp" android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_alignParentRight="true"`. This works, but it's a workaround. If anybody has an explanation what was going on, I'd still be interested. I suspect the problem was the gravity tag, which somehow made Android ignore constraints further down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fragments that are embedded in XML layout resources define their content view's layout params. While the layout of the `Fragment` was defined to match the parent's dimensions, the `Fragment` itself was defined to wrap to it's content.

Since the second child was not anchored to the parent's right except through the defined gravity (which cannot apply until the dimensions have been measured), it was positioned at the base anchor points (0, 0). The first child's layout was defined to be to the left of the second child, which was out of the parent's bounds. The `RelativeLayout` measured it's width to wrap to the content by matching the width of the second child.

If you explicitly anchor the second child to the opposite side to the base (by adding `android:layout_alignParentRight="true"` to the layout attributes in your case), then the `RelativeLayout` will always consume the maximum available space in that dimension (if the parent has defined and bounded dimensions).

There doesn't seem to be any mechanism for `RelativeLayout` to both wrap to it's content and also define custom base anchoring points. It would have been nice if the gravity was used as a hint to determine the anchor points at measuring time. Changing the layout direction to right-to-left can be used as a hack for flipping the anchor point on the horizontal axis. Note that in that case you should not define any custom gravity, as there is a [bug](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=114948) that would cause the layout to be offset incorrectly to the left in that case.